# How to fetch only image from smart albums in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, fetch, photo

I try to fetch image using this code, but catch all media (not image)

```
     let smartAlbumsOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        smartAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .albumRegular, options: smartAlbumsOptions)
        let collections = smartAlbums.firstObject!
        let image = PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue
        smartAlbumsOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", image)
        fetchAssetsResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collections, options: smartAlbumsOptions)
```

a getted all media on folders but not separate on photo/ video
how to fix that?

Comment: I think mediaType is only supported for assets, not for collections. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phfetchoptions#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014396

Comment: @EricAya i use this documentation
but i not all understand